# Changing a Views textLabel from a different View

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiview

I have a custom class called `colorChangerViewClass` that inherits from `UIView`:

```
class colorChangerViewClass: UIView {


@IBOutlet weak var controller: ViewController!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // I want to change a textLabel in the main ViewController based on the current finger position here!
    }

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // And here aswell!
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { ... }


func setColor(color: UIColor) {
    self.backgroundColor = color
}

}
```

Inside the `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods I want to change a `textLabel` in the main ViewController (a different one) based on the current finger position.

**What is the best way to establish communication between the two classes `colorChangerViewClass` and `ViewController`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are trying to communicate child to parent, there are several ways from which you can gain desired out put.

**1.Delegation**

**2. Notification**

**3. Passing Parent instance object to child (similar as delegate)**

*I am demonstrating with delegate, you can use delegation as:-*

**1. Declare** 
Declare a protocol somewhere out side your ColorChangerViewClass

```
protocol ColorChangerViewClassDelegate:class {
    func fingerDidMoved()
    }
```

**2. Create delegate var inside your ColorChangerViewClass**

```
class ColorChangerViewClass: UIView {

        //declare delegate var

        weak var delegate:ColorChangerViewClassDelegate?

        @IBOutlet weak var controller: ViewController!

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            // I want to change a textLabel in the main ViewController based on the current finger position here!
            self.notify()

        }

        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            self.notify()
            // And here aswell!
        }

        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        }

        func setColor(color: UIColor) {
            self.backgroundColor = color
        }

        func notify() {
            if let delegate = self.delegate {
                delegate.fingerDidMoved()
            }
        }

        }
```

**3. Set Delegate of your view to the controller**

```
class SomeVC:UIViewController,ColorChangerViewClassDelegate {

    var myLabel = UILabel()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //your view
            let theView = ColorChangerViewClass() // you might need auto layout or frame declared on your view to define view size
            theView.delegate = self
        }

        //MARK:-deleate method of view
        func fingerDidMoved() {
           // set text from here 
           self.myLabel.text = "Your text"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are too close to solve the problem, you need to set the reference of your `ViewController` to `controller` property of your `colorChangerViewClass`. Also no need to declare `controller` as outlet so change its declaration like below.

```
var controller: ViewController?
```

Now in `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` use this controller to access `textLabel`

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.controller?.textLabel.text = //set text
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.controller?.textLabel.text = //set text
}
```

Now in your `ViewController` class where you are creating object of `colorChangerViewClass` set the `controller` property of it.

```
@IOutlet var colorView: colorChangerViewClass!

//set controller property in viewDidLoad
colorView.controller = self
```

**Note:** class name always start with Uppercase letters so it would be better if you changed your class name to `ColorChangerViewClass` from `colorChangerViewClass`.

Comment: I do not understand the last part of your answer. 
I created the instance of `ColorChangerViewClass` in the interface builder. Not programmatically.

When trying to use your code Xcode understandably complains about `colorChangerView` being invalidly redeclared.

Comment: If you are setting this class in interface builder then you can create Outlet of this view in your ViewController and set the controller property in `viewDidLoad`.